# How to define DO NOTHING in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am displaying a confirm box in my app. When the user clicks on `Okay`, I close the window
when user clicks on `Cancel`, I want to do nothing but stay on the same page.

What should I write in place of DO_NOTHING?

```
    <a href="#" onclick="confirm('Do you wan to close the application ?')?window.close():DO_NOTHING')">Close the application ?</a>
```

If I keep it empty it does not work. If I write any random string it works but displays `string undefined` error.

Comment: `() => null` // function that does nothing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just have this instead:

```
onclick="if (confirm('Do you wan to close the application ?')) window.close();"
```

No point of using the `x?y:z` if you don't intend to use it "fully".

Answer (score 32):

Try using `void(0)`

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirm('Do you wan to close the application ?')?window.close():void(0)')">Close the application ?</a>
```

Comment: `void` is an operator, not a function. There is no need for a grouping operator so `void 0` is sufficient. There are better answers to the question, but this one is better than most.

Answer (score 5):

try `return false;` or `null`

```
// What should I write in place of DO_NOTHING
    <a href="#" onclick="confirm('Do you wan to close the application ?')?window.close():return false')">Close the application ?</a>
```

Comment: If I add `return false` then even `confirm` is not displayed. adding `null` worked. Thanks Thor.

Answer (score 5):

`void(0)` or `null` would be fine, but consider using a plain `if(confirm(...))`

Answer (score 1):

I think simply `return` or `return false` should do.

I usually don't use inline javascript, if the onClick code were in a function attached to the onClick event, you would probably use Event.cancel() or similar...
(If that's the actual link it would not do anything anyway if the event bubbled through, only jump to an non-existen blank anchor)

Comment: If I add any of this then even `confirm` is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

`return false;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try an empty object like this

```
<a onclick="confirm('xyz')?window.close():{}">well</a>
```

In fact any stupit thing like `:function(){}` `eval()` should do the job well.

Comment: well I obviously meant an existing variable x :)

Comment: Ohh..Then it will. I wanted to avoid unnecessary use of other variables.

Comment: Any of your existing variables will do. Also try any empty js functions like eval().

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="confirm('Do you wan to close the application ?')?window.close():() => {}')"
```

Arrow function that return an empty object, it basically does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `&&`?

```html
<a href="#" onclick="confirm('Do you want to close the application ?') && window.close()">Close the application ?</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
onclick="return confirm('Do you wan to close the application ?')"
```

Comment: -1 it will only return the value but will not execute the `window.close`.. so if the user clicks "yes", the page will be redirected to the href of the link

Comment: But what about the `window.close()`?

Answer (score -1):

`condition ? function call : function call`  is not how ?: works .

Should be

`eval(condition? function call : function call/ blank string)`

Comment: @Shadow Wizard  I was just posting why the OP was getting the error . The form the OP is using wont run , as does a few upvoted answers here :) .       test url http://jsfiddle.net/nhS2m/ . Tested in ie8 , ff 3.6

Comment: indeed, but the problem is with `void` not any function, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/nhS2m/1/ it works just fine with custom function.